# Are KD trees still efficient when most/all of the attributes are discrete and distance is equivalent?

Tags: data-structures, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

It's always touted that KD trees are great for nearest neighbor searches.  However, if your data set is all discrete values, with no real distance metric, are they still efficient?

For example, if your attributes were things something like `[black, blue, red], [bread, milk, cheese], [right, left, straight, curved]` There is no continuity, and the only way to measure distance would be hamming distance (where we check how many are equivalent to the testing example).  Do KD trees still hold up efficiently in these scenarios?  How come?

Comment: the 1-D analog certainly still seems to work (we can assign an enumeration to help the tree construction), but the point is that one does not have to examine all leaves in the tree to find matches.. ??

Comment: I would venture to guess that if you're using a datastructure such as a KD-tree which is based upon the ability to formulate some discrete measure with data that doesn't lend itself to measurability then you're using the wrong data structure.  That said, I'd ask this question on theoretical computer science stackexchange instead.  You'd probably get a better/more indepth answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm actually just trying to teach myself about some machine learning methods, working on nearest neighbors now.  KD trees seem to be the standard data structure for this algorithm.  Just unsure as to how it adapts to different data sets

Comment: I would also consider giving more thought to the metric.  I don't know all the attributes in your real problem, but if, say, color has values such as "black", "green", and "chartreuse" I wouldn't think of the distance between black and green as the same as the distance between green and chartreuse.

Comment: in any case, `d(x, y) = \delta_{x,y}` works for the discrete values, and fulfils the conditions for a metric in the mathematical sense, so i guess it should work[?]

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be appropriate to consider what a (nearest) "neighbor" would be if there is no metric on your set of values. Specifically, how does one define whether elements in the set are near or far from one another without a measure of distance?

That being said, KD-trees can work for discrete sets. Some of the efficiently essentially comes from being able to divide data so we can eliminate chunks of elements with one comparison, like any other balanced tree. But, the most natural use is on sets that have a useful and meaningful topology.

Answer (score 0):

KD trees still require a notion of dimensions. Your examples do not describe data points in terms of dimensions, discrete or not, so a KD tree does not apply. Furthermore, KD trees rely on some inequalities that a mapping of such data onto dimensions may not have.

That being said, discrete data isn't a problem if it maps neatly as aforementioned -- computers only store discrete approximations.